# Show alert box when go through by direct access?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

```
<script>
{
document.referrer;
alert(document.referrer);
}
</script>
```

I want the alert box to appear when I go by direct access by entering url,

If I go by button it should show the webpage, can anyone help me do it.

http://183.82.33.232:8095/finsafe/calculator/sip.html

If I type the above link then only it should show alert box and if I go through button it should go normally, now can anyone explain me clearly,

Comment: `if(!document.referrer)
alert('direct access');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is empty when you access the page by direct link.

```
// If document.referrer is empty

if (document.referrer === '') {
    alert(document.referrer, 'your alert if your acces by direct link');
}
```

Not sure if this is an answer since your question is unclear.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it.